# Secure code makes exploitation easier with CPU vulnerabilities?

Tags: exploit-development, secure-coding, spectre, meltdown, cpu

I researched CPU vulnerabilities in the past, such as Specter and Meltdown.

I read that one of those attacks is made easier if the code is a certain way. I cannot remember if it was related to being efficiently written, securely written, or some other reason. However, now I need this quote I cannot find it anywhere.

What factors in the code make Spectre and/or Meltdown easier to perform the attack?

Comment: There's no short answer to this question. Coding aspects will affect the way that these hardware vulnerabilities are exploited. But that doesn't mean that security enhancements in the code make it easier or more difficult implicitly.

Comment: I suggest you consult the original research paper. It may have something to do with branch prediction.

Comment: I think branch prediction is easier the better wrote the code or something?